# Is it me or does Grammarly have it wrong: “Your” vs “You're”

Tags: orthography, pronouns, contractions, possessive-determiners

My friend and I are having a debate whether the following is wrong

> your saying Grammarly is wrong and your smarter.

since it's the wrong *your*.

But Grammarly seems to not pick up on it, is it wrong? Surely it'd be *You're* since *Your* is possessive.

Comment: I think **you're** right, but don't call me Shirley.

Comment: He's just stubborn :)

Comment: _your saying Grammarly is wrong_ is very formal and awkward here but is grammatical in and of itself... although what comes after matters, e.g. "Your saying Grammarly is wrong may well turn out to be correct." _your smarter_ proves itself.

Comment: On what basis does Grammarly have it wrong? A link to the Grammarly page that supposedly says "your" is acceptable here would seem to be in order.

Comment: Which "your" is Grammarly underling, the first, the second, or both?

Comment: Only the second _your_ is misspelled. The first one is a simple gerund subject, in the possessive: _Your saying Grammarly was wrong has set of a wave of selling on the NYSE_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct sentence should be 'You're saying Grammarly is wrong and you're smarter' which is short for 'You are saying Grammarly is wrong and you are smarter'. The phrase 'your saying Grammarly is wrong' is only correct if it is interpreted as a noun phrase, as in the example 'Your saying Grammarly is wrong is correct'.

Answer (score 0):

Umm, I think your friend is right. I'm not sure. You're saying Grammarly is wrong and your smarter is correct in Grammarly too and on here but it depends on English context so both of you are right but you would need to give context if he or you said this if not you/him/her should've. So my final decision is your friend is right unless he didn't give any context. Sorry!

Comment: Why is "your smarter" correct?

Comment: If you change the sentence to "Your saying 'Grammarly is wrong' proves your friend smarter."